# What happens to a radar signal when it meets with a superconductor?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, solid-state-physics, superconductivity, radar

A radar system has a transmitter that emits radio waves called a radar signal, consisting of electromagnetic radiation. What happens when it meets with a strong superconductor, considering the fact that a superconductor expels magnetic fields. Will there be any reflection back to the radar receiver, or will the signal be refracted?

Comment: They are mostly about waves with energy. Radar waves are usually affiliated with wavelength and frequency than energy since they carry low energy photons. Will be happy if i can get a reply based on radar waves. Thanks so much.

Comment: @KyleOman is there actually an answer to this question there? Something along the lines of "what will happen" to add to the "here's how to think about it"? Maybe it's there and I'm just missing it. I do see electrodynamics and Higgs mechanism answers, but that doesn't really help this "what will happen?" question.

Comment: This is just a side note - usually when there is refraction there is also some reflection - not necessarily because it's a metal, but any time an EM wave (or most other waves) has to change speed suddenly at an interface, some if it is usually reflected just to make sure all the conserved quantities are conserved. Like seeing your reflection in a glass window.

Comment: Someone show me the "what happens" answer - I don't see it.

Comment: Seems pretty clearly stated: "if the energy of the photon before it reaches the superconductor is less than the energy gap, this photon will be reflected. If the initial energy is larger, we have a superposition of a transmitted and a reflected component for the wave function", you may also be interested in [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/71901/why-arent-superconductors-shiny?noredirect=1&lq=1), which is also closed as a duplicate of the same question.